# Lumen: Create default route that return 404

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

In Laravel you can show a 404 page just on creating a file `404.blade.php` in the errors folder according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37721352/8583669).

But how can I return a custom response in my Lumen API if the entered request don't match any of mine in `web.php`. So something like:

```php
// ...
$router->default(function () {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'INVALID_ROUTE'], 404);
});
```

Comment: I think there is not a fallback method on lumen, but you can handle it on App\Exceptions\Handler class. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215716/custom-404-page-in-lumen

Comment: This post is to render a view but I want to return a json response.

Comment: You can return a json response like the one in your question. Just change the response in the return `if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
        return response()->json(['error' => 'INVALID_ROUTE'], 404);
    }` and add this line up the top of the Handler file: `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;`. I don't have a lumen project to test it but should work.

Comment: The Handler file referred to is in App\Exceptions\Handler.php