# Why does a request to an undefined route result in 401 unauthenticated in Laravel

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-401, laravel-nova, laravel-sanctum

A Laravel 8 application with Sanctum.

When I send a request to a defined route using Postman with an access token the response is correct. I'm happy with this.

When I send a request to a defined route using Postman without an access token the response is 401 Access denied. I'm happy with this.

When I send a request to an undefined route using Postman with an access token the response is 401 Unauthenticated. I'm NOT happy with this. I want a more appropriate response, such as 404.

I don't know how to choose what code from my application to include this question. Please ask me for whatever might be useful and I'll add it.

Update:

Thanks to the answer by @MartinZeitler I worked out that the problem is caused by me making Nova accessible at `/` instead of `/nova`.

I did this in `/config/nova.php` by changing

`'path' => '/nova',`
to
`'path' => '/',`.

If I revert this to `'/nova'` then everything works as I expect it to.

But I need Nova at `/`, so what can I do?

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally restricted access to your 404 page? Maybe a dumb question, but I only ask because I know a guy who actually did this, who may or may not be me

Comment: @Don'tPanic I don't know how to restrict access to my 404 page. Which doesn't mean I haven't done it!

Comment: This was not something I did in Laravel (okay, it was me). It was in a symfony app that restricted routes based on regular expressions, and I unintentionally restricted every route in the app. After looking at the sanctum docs, it looks like you have to explicitly protect each route, so it doesn't look like that could have happened in this case. Just a thought.

Comment: checked at Laravel 8 with sanctum - undefined route with token - 404, not 401. maybe you define auth middleware in Kernel for all routes?

Comment: @cja Please share your route `api.php`

Comment: Can you review this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31621512/13875884

Comment: You had to make some modification in the middleware priority or Service Providers to get this behavior, because the default behavior of a Laravel + Sanctum installation should return a 404 error instead of 401. I have tested it myself a few moments ago and this is how it works by default.

Maybe placing the content of `app\Http\Kernel.php` could help us.

Comment: @cja does my answer helped you. if not you can share your `App\Http\Kernel.php` in order to find out the problem

Comment: I don't have the source code of Nova but maybe the undefined route you request beings captured by Nova because you run Nova at root `/` path, you can try disable auth and send a request to that undefined route to make sure it's not captured by Nova

Comment: what are all the composer package you are using

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer a routing question without, eg. the output of `php artisan route:list`.
The 401 likely comes from Sanctum or from missing a catch-all route `Route::any('', [ ... ])`.
Since Laravel [8.26.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.26.0), there is a new [`missing()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-missing-model-behavior) method available.

Beside that, my best bet would be `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel` ...

```
/**
 * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
 *
 * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewarePriority = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

401 & 404 are exceptions that exit the application flow from normal behavior.
in your situation it seems The **401 exception** get executed sooner, and doesn't let the 404 to get executed.

if these **exception controls** has been placed in the middlewares, you could
change the execution order of middlewares from The `App\Http\Kernel`

for route middleware from `$middlewarePriority`

for global middleware from `$middleware`

but The url not match error (**The 404**) occurs here :

`Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher` The method: `match()`, and it is out of middlewares scope.

but how to prevent the 401 from running first?
this exception is thrown from the **authentication middleware**,

The Middlewares can get called in 3 places in the laravel:

1. as **Global Middleware**
2. as **Route Parameter Middleware**
3. only get called in the **Controller's Constructor**

I have tested, that if The middleware is **Global** it gets executed, before the **Url not match 404**.

In the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes), it is mentioned that:

> The withoutMiddleware method can only remove route middleware and does not apply to global middleware.

I would translated it to:

> The **Global** Middleware has executed before we get to the **routes** files

### TL;DR

so I guess, You have added the **authentication** middleware in the `$middleware`.
and I think you have to move it (`'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class`) to the `$routeMiddleware` array.

then use the `middleware(auth:sanctum)` in The **routes** files or the **RouteServiceProvider**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but this is not what I've done.

Comment: @cja : from your question, is there two types of 401 error? ( Access denied & Unauthenticated )

Comment: no (here's an extra few characters to allow comment to submit)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe need to check a FormRequest class which handle your method in the controller, and then check method `authorize` he is should return when true for example

```
public function authorize()
{
   return auth('sanctum')->check(); // or for test just return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to the **Handler.php** file in the **register** function in Exceptions directory.

```
  $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
      //json response
      return $this->error('Not found', 404);

      // return 404 as html view
      // abort(404);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom exception handling to handle all exceptions.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (\Exception $e, $request) {
        if($request->is('api/*'))
            return $this->handleException($request, $e);
    });
}

public function handleException($request, \Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
       return $this->sendValidationError($exception->errors());
    }

    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return $this->sendError([], 404, __('message.page_not_found'));
    }

    if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        return $this->sendError([], 401, __('auth.unauthorized'));
    }

    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
        return $this->sendError([], 404, __('message.not_found'));
    }

    if($request->is('api/*')) {
       return $this->sendError([], 501, __('message.error_message'));
    }
}
```